# How does nodejs manage its versions?

Tags: node.js

I am working on window10 and want to install nodejs 7.x. I want to use node7 because I have a mac os which is using this version. But I couldn't find the version for 7.x from this line: https://nodejs.org/en/. I only found `6.*` and `8.*`. I wonder how nodejs manager its versions. Why can't I download the version 7 directly from the official website? Do I really need to upgrade it from `npm` command?
I tried to use `npm-windows-upgrade` to update node version on windows but found the latest version I can install is `5.0.3`. I am totally confused about nodejs versions. How can I install a nodejs version `7.x`?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were literally two clicks away from viewing a list of all releases...

From https://nodejs.org/en/, click "Downloads", then scroll down on https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and click "Previous Releases" which takes you to a list of all releases [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

Answer (score -2):

You can use nvm.

> npm install nvm -g
>
> nvm use [version]